# React Material Box, use RGB function

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to use rgb function in Material Box. How can this be done? This is not working.

**Original Code:**

```
    <Box
      width={24}
      style={{
        background: `rgb(${appointmentReasonView.rgbColorView})`,
        whiteSpace: 'pre-wrap',
      }}
    >
```

**New Code Attempt:**

```
    <Box
      width={24}
      whiteSpace="preWrap"
      background={rgb(${appointmentReasonView.rgbColorView})}
    >
```

> Error: Cannot find name 'rgb'

Comment: The property of `background` doesn't exist in the Box component as far as I know and based on the component's docs https://mui.com/material-ui/api/box/
What you are trying to do here? can you give a few more details please? Thanks

Comment: we are trying to convert a rgb color, (r,g,b) string from API into a css background color cc @Akis

Comment: The way you have it in the original code using the inline styled is an ok solution and should work, other ways for example that I would suggest is to use styled components or the `sx` property depending the material-ui version. What I meant with my question earlier is if the code is not working or you are trying to find the best way to do it, as the original code should work.

Comment: hi @Akis my team wants me to stop using style, and place as box component,  if you know answer for styled component, that will work, please place as answer, and I can send points, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With styled components you can do it like this:

```
import { styled } from "@mui/system";

const BoxStyled = styled(Box)`
  background: ${({ background }) => `rgb(${background})`};
`;

<BoxStyled
  width={24}
  whiteSpace="preWrap"
  background={appointmentReasonView.rgbColorView} // Pass here the value from api
/>
```

Let me know if it helps (the value from the api should be rendered inside the rgb in the styled component. So when you inspect the lement it should show a correct css value like `background: rgb(255 0 0))`. Here is a working [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/green-dust-s1podk?file=/demo.tsx).

Comment: I am not using emotion/styled, but styled from styled components,

Comment: @mattsmith5 I have updated my original answer and added a codesandbox to play with. Let me know if you have any questions. Thanks

Comment: @mattsmith5 was the above solution the answer you were looking for?